# How to get text from <li> elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have:

```
<ul> 
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text2 </li>
</ul>
```

Right now I get the text from `<li>` like this:

```
result = page.css(' ul li').text
```

The problem is, as a result I get a string with no spaces like

```
text1text2
```

I want it to be divided with `<br>`, like `text1<br>text2<br>`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "[Searching a XML/HTML Document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)"
:

> methods xpath and css actually return a NodeSet, which acts very much
>   like an array, and contains matching nodes from the document.

So, if you want to concatenate all texts from all `<li>` tags, then you should work with the `css` method result as with a collection:

```
page.css('ul li') # selects all li tags and returns collection of Node objects
    .map(&:text) # maps collection of li nodes into array of corresponding texts
    .join('<br>') # concatenates all nodes texts into a single string with <br> separator
```

See: http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

Comment: so if I write `array = page.css('ul li').map(&:text) ` I will get an array of text in `<li>` elements?

Comment: and what does this mean `&:text`

Comment: It's an equivalent to text method call for each element of array. .map { |e| e.text }
http://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-ruby-idiom-map-with-symbol/